# haskell [[Char]] to [[Int]]

Tags: list, haskell, char, int

I've got problem with a Haskell program.
I'm trying to change `[[Char]]` to `[[Int]]`
I've got

```
["2","2","1","2,2","1"]
```

list of char list
and I'm trying to change it to `[[Int]]`

```
[[2],[2],[1],[2,2],[1]]
```

I've tried

```
f :: [String] -> [Int]
f = map read
```

but it gives me

> [2,2,1,*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: That's because it can not parse a `"2,2"` to an `Int`, or at least not directly.

Comment: Hint: your signature for `f` is not entirely correct.

Comment: can you explain or give me a hint  how to parse it not directly

Comment: you can split it with comma as a separator.

Comment: I could imagine a list like that coming up because somebody called `lines` on the contents of a CSV file. If that's the situation you are in, then I strongly recommend using a real CSV parser library (say, cassava), so that you correctly handle escaping and the like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that this fails is because a string `"2,2"` can not be converted to an `Int` itself: this is a digit followed by a comma, followed by a digit. An `Int` is parsed by an optional minus sign, followed by some digits, and some extra possibilities like hexadecimal numbers, but let us ignore these for now.

The type signature you specify for `f` is however incorrect, based on the expected output. Your output type seems to be a list of *lists* of `Int`s, so `[[Int]]`. That means that you should specify `f` as:

```
f :: [String] -> [[Int]]
f = ...
```

We thus need to read every `String` to an `[Int]`. We can not use `read` directly here, since `read`ing to an `[Int]` expects the string to start and end with *square brackets*. We can however add these manually like:

```
f :: [String] -> [[Int]]
f = map (\s -> read ('[' : s ++ "]"))
```

or a *point-free* version:

```
f :: [String] -> [[Int]]
f = map (read . ('[' :) . (++ "]"))
```

For example:

```
Prelude> f ["2","2","1","2,2","1"] 
[[2],[2],[1],[2,2],[1]]
```

## Towards *safer* parsing with `readMaybe`

Parsing from `String`s like in the above way is of course not very "*safe*", since it is possible that the `String` does not follow the format. We can make this more safe and use for example [**`readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe):

```
import Text.Read(readMaybe)

f :: [String] -> [Maybe [Int]]
f = map (readMaybe . ('[' :) . (++ "]"))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Text.Read> f ["2", "3;2", "4,7,3", "bla"]
[Just [2],Nothing,Just [4,7,3],Nothing]
```

we can omit the failed reads for example by using [**`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes):

```
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)
import Text.Read(readMaybe)

f :: [String] -> [[Int]]
f = catMaybes . map (readMaybe . ('[' :) . (++ "]"))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe Text.Read> f ["2", "3;2", "4,7,3", "bla"]
[[2],[4,7,3]]
```

or as [@dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116208/haskell-char-to-int/56116406?noredirect=1#comment98866645_56116406) said, we can use [**`traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse) to return an `[[Int]]` result wrapped in a `Just` if *all* parsing succeeded, and `Nothing` otherwise:

```
import Text.Read(readMaybe)

f :: [String] -> Maybe [[Int]]
f = traverse (readMaybe . ('[' :) . (++ "]"))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Text.Read> f ["2","2","1","2,2","1"] 
Just [[2],[2],[1],[2,2],[1]]
Prelude Text.Read> f ["2", "3;2", "4,7,3", "bla"]
Nothing
```

## Parse with error messages with `readEither`

We can obtain an error message wrapped in a `Left` in case the parsing fails by using [**`readEither :: Read a => String -> Either String a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readEither):

```
import Text.Read(readEither)

f :: [String] -> [Either String [Int]]
f = map (readEither . ('[' :) . (++ "]"))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Text.Read> f ["2", "3;2", "4,7,3", "bla"]
[Right [2],Left "Prelude.read: no parse",Right [4,7,3],Left "Prelude.read: no parse"]
```

and use `traverse` in the same way to obtain an error message wrapped in a `Left` or the complete result in a `Right`:

```
import Text.Read(readEither)

f :: [String] -> Either String [[Int]]
f = traverse (readEither . ('[' :) . (++ "]"))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Text.Read> f ["2","2","1","2,2","1"] 
Right [[2],[2],[1],[2,2],[1]]
Prelude Text.Read> f ["2", "3;2", "4,7,3", "bla"]
Left "Prelude.read: no parse"
```

Here, like @dfeuer says, it does not really shows much information. There are however parsers that can provide more informative parsing errors.

Comment: Good point about `catMaybes`. Maybe you should add `traverse` and I should delete my otherwise inferior answer.

Comment: `readEither`, sadly, produces only useless error messages. The underlying parsers lack proper error handling support. Techniques like that become useful when you upgrade from `Read` to a real parsing system like `megaparsec`, `attoparsec`, `optparse-applicative`, `cassava`, etc.